# Wordpress hacked - homepage returns wp-config.php contents

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site that was left unmanaged since it was a voluntary project and got "hacked" most likely due to a weak user password since I noticed thousands of spam posts on 3 users only.

I wanted to clean the database however somehow I managed to break the site. Now when I load homepage in browser it loads contents from wp-config.php (with database password and everything) without any wp styles (CSS etc).

I have looked at redirections, .htaccess and errors, however, I found nothing.

What is causing this?

Comment: My best guess is that Wordpress has a server-side vulnerability in the website's sandbox environment, and due to the hacker breaching it the passwords are visible.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps to manually update WP files - it looks like the hosting anti-virus service removed infected files, thus removing wp core files.

Manual WP update: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update